# Get Icon from another android Application

Tags: android, icons, package

How do I get to the Icon Launcher from another Android application on the device if I know its Package Name?

Example

```
String googlePackageName = "com.google.maps";

Drawable googleIcon = googlePackageName.getIconLauncher() or something.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use PackagerManager's [getApplicationIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28java.lang.String%29)() for this task:

```
Drawable appIcon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.google.maps");
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? Write the exact line code. Please.

Comment: Interestingly this does not work in Compose. 
val drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app.packageName)
Icon(
    drawable.toBitmap(config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).asImageBitmap()
    , contentDescription = "Icon", modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp),
    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
)

it gives a round filled circle.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question. Never heard of before.
But I guess this should be the solution:

```
Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snipped should point you in the right direction:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setPackage( packageName );
final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = pm.queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
if( pkgAppsList.size() > 0 ) {
    this.url = pkgAppsList.get(0).activityInfo.name;
    icon = pkgAppsList.get(0).activityInfo.loadIcon( pm );
    this.displayName = pkgAppsList.get(0).activityInfo.loadLabel( pm ).toString();
    this.module = pkgAppsList.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
    this.isExternal = true;
    this.count = count;
}
```